# Rails ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken All browsers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, session, passenger

I'm having an issue with one user.  No matter what he does he ends up getting throwing an ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken error.  I have tried having him clear his browser's cache, cookies, etc.  He gets this using both FireFox and Internet Explorer.  I'm at a loss as to why this would be occurring for just him.  Everything I do in every browser works fine.

He is running Windows Vista Home.

Our stack:

- Ubuntu 9.10
- Ruby 1.8.7-248
- Rails 2.3.9
- Passenger 2.2.11
- Apache 2.2.12

Thanks!

Comment: "No Matter what he does"? Does it happen when he's submitting data via a form in some fashion to the app?

Comment: He said it happens anytime he submits a form on Internet Explorer 8, FireFox 3.6.10, and Chrome.

Comment: Please show the HTTP response headers from the affacted PC and page (look it up in Chrome Developer Tools in the Resources tab, or using Firebug in Firefox). Compare with unaffected PCs. I'm pretty sure there's a badly tuned caching mechanism between your server and the user or some firewall which tampers with the cookies for pseudo-security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use page, action or fragment caching? Be sure you are not caching the authenticity token.

Comment: No, I'm not using any caching.

Comment: My gut is telling me that it was the upgrade to Rails 2.3.9 from 2.3.8, I know there were issues with the Database session store, however we are using the cookie session store.

Comment: Ok, my gut was wrong.  I downgraded to Rails 2.3.8, had the user try again.  The problem is stil there.